# How to ensure that Laravel 5.5 is running a test?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have some methods in my app that I check for `if (env('APP_DEBUG'))` on and return `true` (or whatever) if we're in debug mode rather than doing a certain DB or API call.

The problem is when I run phpunit, the app is still in debug mode, so it doesn't "really" run the test against the actual code.

Is it possible to check if a test is being run, so I could do `if (env('APP_DEBUG') || $testing)`? Or is there a better way to handle this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're looking for `App::runningUnitTests()`.

Remember that you shouldn't use env() outside your configuration files, instead use `config('app.debug')`. This ensures that your code works with a cached configuration.

It's impossible to answer "is there a better way" without having more details.

Comment: Thanks-- that's perfect. Can you explain 'you shouldn't use env() outside your configuration files'?

Comment: @user101289 I'm somewhat late to answer now, but it's how the cached configuration work. A cached configuration will build the config files once and and store them, and not populate the environment from `.env` anymore. Thus the env() call will return null for your application environment variables. Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching

Answer (score 2):

Rather than update your application to check if tests are running, you could disable debug mode in your test environment by updating your `phpunit.xml` file:

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="false"/>
</php>
```

Also, you should not use the `env` function outside of configuration files. The `env` function will just return null if you are using the config cache

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#configuration-caching

> If you execute the config:cache command during your deployment process, you should be sure that you are only calling the env function from within your configuration files.

Use `config('app.debug')` instead of `env('APP_DEBUG')`.